# run a shell command from a specific directory in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

How do I execute a shell command (eg, `git gui`) from a specific directory? I'd prefer a cross-platform approach that doesn't depend shell operators like `&&` or `;` because I need this to run on Windows and unix. (For example, calling `cd /path/to/dir && git gui` won't work on Windows because `&&` is not valid.)

I tried:

```lisp
(async-shell-command (concat "cd \""
  (replace-regexp-in-string 
    "/" "\\\\" (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))) "\" ; git gui"))
```

That fails because for whatever reason the shell thinks `; git gui` is part of the path, and it reports: `The system cannot find the path specified.`

So, I'd rather not deal with shell quirks and I'm hoping there's an elisp function that sets the directory for `shell-command` or `async-shell-command`. I tried:

```lisp
 (shell-process-pushd (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name)))
 (shell-command "git gui")
 (shell-process-popd nil)
```

That had no effect: `git gui` always opens in my home directory. (Also, `shell-process-pushd/popd` are not documented.)

This also doesn't work:

```lisp
(start-process "gitgui" nil "git" "gui")
```

Neither does this:

```lisp
(let '(bufdir (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))) 
       (with-temp-buffer
         (print bufdir)
         (cd bufdir)
         (shell-command "git gui")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(shell-command)` *does* use the the buffer's `default-directory`, which means there is no reason to `cd` to the buffer's directory.

The problem in my case was that I was mistakenly running `git gui` on a buffer that didn't have an associated `.git/` directory.

Answer (score 12):

Are you sure you're using the trailing slash to indicate directory name in emacs-lisp?

```
(let ((default-directory "~/.emacs.d"))
  (shell-command-to-string "echo $PWD"))
        ;;; ⇒ "/Users/me"

(let ((default-directory "~/.emacs.d/"))
  (shell-command-to-string "echo $PWD"))
        ;;; ⇒ "/Users/me/.emacs.d"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(let ((default-directory "~/.emacs.d/")) (shell-command "ls"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but `default-directory` is *already* set to the desired directory. It simply doesn't have any effect on `shell-command`. BTW, I'm not attached to `shell-command`, if there's some other function I don't know about I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: `default-directory` can be set as _local_ and _global_ and it is just overrided. There is a difference between using `default-directory` over `let` and just set it without binding to command or buffer. `(let ((default-directory "~/.emacs.d/")) (call-process "ls" nil 't))` works for me too.

Comment: Well, I'm guessing you aren't on Windows, or there is a bug with the [Windows emacs build](http://chocolatey.org/packages/Emacs) I'm using. On Mac OS X homebrew emacs build, even just `(shell-command "git gui")` works for me, without having to `(let ...)`. What emacs version and OS are you using?

Comment: I tried in my old emacs in Windows (22 version): `(let ((default-directory "t:/")) (shell-command "dir"))` works fine.

Comment: Turns out I was running `git gui` on a file that didn't have a `.git/` directory. And yes, I feel stupid.